# Is it allowed to only substitute one of several fresh variables in a natural deduction proof step?

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am working on the following proof: ∀x∀y (x = g(y) → f (x) = y) $\vdash$ ∀x f (g(x)) = x and I have tried solving it as:

`∀x∀y (x = g(y) → f(x)=y)            premise
  | x0  x0 = g(x0)                   assumption
  |     ∀y (x0 = g(y) → f(x0)=y)     ∀xe 1
  |     (x0 = g(x0) → f(x0)=x0)      ∀ye 3
  |     f(x0) = x0                   →e 4, 2
  |     f(g(x0)) = x0                =e 2, 5
∀x f(g(x)) = x                       ∀xi 2--6`

It is the `=e 2, 5` I am asking about. Is it allowed to only substitute on of the x0s like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

I think that the above derivation does not work...

You correctly instantiate the premise with $x_0$ getting :

> $∀y \ (x_0 = g(y) \to f(x_0)=y)$

and then we instantiate again :

> $(x_0 = g(x_0) → f(x_0)=x_0)$.

Assuming :

> > $x_0=g(x_0)$ --- [a]

after $\to$-elim we may use $=$-elim to substitute only one occurrence of $x_0$, getting :

> $f(g(x_0))=x_0$.

But now we have problems...

First, we have the open assumption [a] with $x_0$ *free*: thus, we cannot apply $\forall$-intro.

Second, also if we apply $\exists$-intro (no restriction) getting :

> $\exists x \ (f(g(x))=x)$

we still have the assumption [a]. Thus out derivation amounts to:

> > $∀x \ ∀y \ (x = g(y) \to f(x)=y), \ x_0=g(x_0) \vdash \exists x \ (f(g(x))=x).$

---

To fix the problem, we have to use the equality axiom:

> $\forall x (x=x)$

as an additional "premise"; being an axiom, it is not an *assumption*, and thus we have no need to discharge it.

Comment: This is true. I fooled myself by writing the free variable on the same line as my assumption. However, thank you for clarifying that it is okay to substitute only one free variable with the =e rule.

Comment: Without giving me the derivation, could you deny or confirm the possibility to prove the sequent given?

Comment: I managed! Thank you @Mauro ALLEGRANZA for your help.